# QBW file via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I try to upload a huge qbw file in chunks using this function.
But the file type is empty and when
I try to open it with a dedicated program , it tells me that the file has an unexpected format.
Also after merging the chunks, they are merged into one huge file,
but the file has 0 kb size.
I tried many contentType,
headers and reader methods to read chunks but the same result.
Can anyone knows what is wrong ?

```
// slice files in chunks
chunky : function(file, loadedSize) {
    let chunkSize = 1048576 ;  //1024*1024; size of one chunk
    var totalFileSize = file.size;  // total size of file
    var noOfChunks = Math.ceil(totalFileSize/chunkSize);
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let blob = file.slice(loadedSize, chunkSize); //a single chunk in starting of step size
    let requestNumber = 1;
  // reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
  // reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  // reader.readAsText(blob);
    reader.onloadend = function (event) {
        if (event.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) { //read request completed
            // no more chunks to send
            if(event.target.result) {
                if ( file.type == '' ){
                    filetype = 'application/octet-stream';
                } else {
                    filetype = file.type;
                }
  
                var dataToBeSent = {
                    bloby: event.target.result,
                    fileName: file.name,
                    fileType: file.type, // empty ??
                    fileSize: totalFileSize,
                    loadedSize: loadedSize,
                    requestNumber: requestNumber
                }
                console.log('dataToBe Sent bloby: ' + event.target.result+ '///'+ file.name+'///'+file.type);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: IntegrationServer.path + '/uploadfileInChuncks?' + jQuery.param(Integration.addfile.requestParams),
                    type: "POST",
                   // method: "POST",
                    data: dataToBeSent,
                   // contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                   // processData: false,
                   // contentType: false
                }).done(function (response) {
                    console.log('received response: ' + response);
                    console.log('loadedSize:: ' + loadedSize + 'totalFileSize:: '+totalFileSize);
                    console.log('requestNumber:: ' + requestNumber + 'noOfChunks'+ noOfChunks);
                   jQuery('.upload_rpogress').html(("Uploaded:" + loadedSize / totalFileSize) * 100);
                    if (requestNumber <= noOfChunks || loadedSize <= totalFileSize) {
                        loadedSize = requestNumber * chunkSize;
                         blob = file.slice(loadedSize, loadedSize+chunkSize+1);
                         console.log('sent blob:: ' + blob);
                        //reader.readAsDataURL( blob );
                        //reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                        //reader.readAsText(blob);
                        requestNumber++;
                    }
                    console.log(requestNumber+ '/' +noOfChunks );
                    if(requestNumber > noOfChunks ) {
                        console.log('merge file with loadedSize' + loadedSize + 'filesize:' + totalFileSize);
                        jQuery('.upload_rpogress').html('Uploaded: 100');
                        Integration.addfile.mergeFile();
                    }
                }).error(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    jQuery('#errorMessage').html(xhr.responseText);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in PHP:

```
 function uploadFileinChuncks($request, $response, $args) {
    
    try {
        $params = $request->getParams();
        $chunk = !empty($params['bloby']) ? $params['bloby'] : '';
        $fileName = !empty($params['fileName']) ? $params['fileName'] : '';
        $loadedSize = !empty($params['loadedSize']) ? $params['loadedSize'] : '';
        $fileNumber = !empty($params['requestNumber']) ? $params['requestNumber'] : '';
        $folderName = self::TEMP_FOLDER . self::QB_FOLDER;
    
        //header('content-type: application/octet-stream');
        if (!is_dir($folderName)) {
            mkdir($folderName, 0777, true);
            chmod($folderName, 0777);
        }
        $destinationFile ='';
        if ($loadedSize >= 0 && !empty($chunk)) {
            $result = base64_encode(implode(',',$chunk));
            $destinationFile = $loadedSize . '-' . $fileNumber . '-' . $fileName;
            if (file_exists($folderName)) {
                $destinationFile = self::TEMP_FOLDER . self::QB_FOLDER . '/' . $destinationFile;
                if(file_exists($destinationFile)) {
                    unlink($destinationFile);
                }
                $fp = fopen($destinationFile, 'a+');
                fwrite($fp, $result);
                fclose($fp);
            }
        }
        return $destinationFile;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why is this question tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: So, this code works well for txt file for example , but not for my .qbw file.
For the .qwb file gives unexpected format when I try to open it.
I have tried to use different reader method  with processData: false and different contentType, but it didn't work.
The qwb file is chunked but the file seems to be corupted.
For txt file, works.